# Why it only returns the first id from my mock up database?

Tags: node.js, api, express, http, backend

In short I am trying to create a simple api that would return the user with the matching id. I use postman to send requests to my localhost created using node.js with express. It works fine when I request the first user but throws in an error when requesting "John". I am coding along a udemy course and can't figure out what the issue is other than the material is outdated. The error is "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

```js
 users: [
    {
      id: "123",
      name: "Sally",
      email: "sally@gmail.com",
      password: "bananas",
      entries: 0,
      joined: new Date(),
    },
    {
      id: "124",
      name: "John",
      email: "john@gmail.com",
      password: "apples",
      entries: 0,
      joined: new Date(),
    },
  ],
};
 
 app.get("/profile/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let found = false;
  database.users.forEach((user) => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      found = true;
      return res.json(user);
    }
    if (!found) {
      res.json("User not found");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description):

> There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the `forEach()` method is the wrong tool.
>
> Early termination may be accomplished with:
>
> - A simple loop
> - A [`for`...`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
>   loop
> - [`Array.prototype.every()`][every]
> - [`Array.prototype.some()`][some]
> - [`Array.prototype.find()`][find]
> - [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`][findIndex]

This means that your loop will run through all elements and in fact call `res.json` multiple times resulting in the `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` error . There are many ways to fix this, here's an one example:

```
app.get("/profile/:id", (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;      
    for (const user of database.users) {
        if (user.id === id) {
            return res.json(user);
        }
    }
    res.json("User not found");
});
```

Comment: Sorry had a busy day. Even after trying with your code the result is still the same. It does find the first user but returns user not found if I search for john's id. I've noticed if I remove the user not found response it works. So maybe i should only have 1 response and should throw a status 404 instead of another json.

Comment: Yep, handling the case when a user not found by responding with status `404` sounds definitely better than returning an error string and status `200` ;)